# react- redux toolkit app issue when trying to get redux data into component

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to add redux data into a component , and I am getting below issue in console.log when I try to check the redux data, could someone able to help me with this

my redux slice is below . please check the bolded line it seems its causing the issue not sure why it happens

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import alladds from '../auth/ads.json'

export const addsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'adds',
    initialState: {
        alladds: alladds
    },
    reducers: {
        addalladds: state => {
            state.alladds = alladds
        },
        
    },
});

export const { addalladds } = addsSlice.actions;
```

**export const selectAddSlice = state => state.addsSlice.alladds**

```
export default addsSlice.reducer;
```

this is my react component

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {  useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {selectAddSlice} from './features/auth/addsSlice'
const Addtocart = () => {
    
     const selectAddSlice1 = useSelector(selectAddSlice);
     const [alladd, setAlladds] = useState(selectAddSlice1)
   
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log(selectAddSlice + "ffffff")
    },)

  return (
    <div>
      {alladd.map((add) => (
        <div key={add.id}>
          <div> {add.addname}</div>
          <div> {add.price}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Addtocart;
```

this is the json data which is in redux
[
{
"addname": "normaladd",
"price": "23",
"id": "1"
},
{
"addname": "advancedadd",
"price": "50",
"id": "2"
},
{
"addname": "premiumadd",
"price": "100",
"id": "3"
}

]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't need to copy** Redux Store data into React local state, you can directly use `selectedAdds` anywhere in the component. The component will re-render whenever data in Redux Store is changed.

```
const selectedAdds = useSelector(selectAddSlice)

// This is not required
// const [alladd, setAlladds] = useState(selectedAdds)

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(selectedAdds)
}, [selectedAdds])
// If you want to see this log, put selectedAdds in dependency array
// So that the Hook will run whenever selectedAdds is changed

return (
  <div>
    {selectedAdds.map((add) => (
    ...
```

But if you really **need** to copy Redux data into local state, you can use a `useEffect`:

```
const [alladd, setAlladds] = useState([]) // Line 1

useEffect(() => {
  setAlladds(selectedAdds) 
  // Set in State whenever selectedAdds is changed; Not 
  // just once at the Line 1 (as initial value of state)
}, [selectedAdds])

return (
  <div>
    {alladd.map((add) => (
    ...
```